# Solving a sequence using arithmetic or geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

The problem statement

1, -3, 4, 1, -3, 4,1, -3, 4,.....

In the sequence above, the first 3 terms repeat without end. What is the sum of the terms of the sequence from the 150th term to the 154th term?

I know the naive approach to solve this problem.

Can I express this sequence in terms of geometric progression or arithmetic progression?

Comment: No need to do that. You can see, for each of 1,2,3, what the sequence is for any number $3k+r$ where $r=1,2,3$ and $k \ge 0.$ Just be careful writing the numbers from 150 to 154 in this form, so you line up the correct things to add. It's only four numbers to add.

Comment: No, you can't express the whole sequence as AP or GP

Comment: @coffeemath Can you please explain it more?

Comment: "Can I express this sequence in terms of geometric progression or arithmetic progression?"  No.

Comment: There is no other way *but* the naive way to do this.  The sequence repeats every three terms, so you figure out where in the repeating pattern the $150$th term is in the pattern be figuring out what the remainder of $150$ is... it's that term in the pattern.  Then you figure out the $151$st, $152$ terms and add them up.

Comment: @coffeemath "It's only four numbers to add."  Nitpick... It's actually 5.

Comment: @Encipher Did you read my answer? I tried to explain it all, maybe you just wanted another way to do it? At least my way didn't require making all the terms.

Comment: @Encipher Technically, you can express it as a sum of (complex) geometric progressions, though that would be a massive overcomplication for the given problem. The periodic sequence can be described by the recurrence $a_{n+3} = a_n$, with characteristic polynomial $\,t^3 -1\,$ having distinct roots $\,1, \omega, \bar\omega\,$, so the general solution is $\,a_n =  \alpha + \beta \omega^n + \gamma \bar\omega^n\,$ where $\,\omega\,$ is a primitive cube root of unity, and $\,\alpha,\beta,\gamma\,$ can be determined from the initial conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to solve adding the $k$th term to the $m$th term in general.

To figure out any $N$th term write $N$ as $3q + r$ where $r$ is the remainder when you divide $N$ by $3$.   If $r = 1,2$ or $0$ then $N$th term is $1, -3$ or $4$ respectively.   This will work to figure out the $k$th term, the $m$th term or any term in-between.

The $k$th to $m$th term will by $(m+1) - k$ terms in total.  $1 + (-3) + 4 = 2$ so every three terms add to $2$.  So the group of $k$ to $m$th terms will have a full set of $\lfloor \frac {(m+1) - k}3 \rfloor$ of these groups of $3$ terms. These will add to $2\times \lfloor \frac {(m+1) - k}3 \rfloor$.

But there might be one are two more terms if $3$ does not divide evenly into $(m+1) - k$.

So.....

Every integer $N$ can be written as $3q + r$ where $r$ is the remainder and $q =\lfloor \frac N3\rfloor$.

Let $(m+ 1)-k = 3q + r$.

If $r = 0$ the sum will be $2\times q$.

If $r =1$ the sum will be $2\times q$ plus one extra term.  Consider that the last term.  Call that $a_m$ and we determine the $m$th term as we did above: Write $m= 3Q + R$ and if $R = 1,2,0$ then $a_m= 1,-3,4$.

So if $r = 1$ the sum will be $2\times q + a_m$.

And if $r =2$ we will have two extra terms and the sum will be $2\times q + a_m + a_{m-1}$.

.....

This is *WAY* overkill for your problem but we could solve $a_{150} + .... +a_{154}$ by noting that there are $(154+1)-150 = 5$ terms.  That is one full triplets of terms that add to $2$.

The two extra terms are $a_{154}$ and $a_{153}$.  $154 = 3*51 + 1$ so $a_{154} = 1$ and $a_{153}$ is the previous term $4$. So the sum is $2 + 1 + 4 = 7$.

....

To see this clearly.  We can figure the $150$th term is $\underbrace{1,-3,4}_3,\underbrace{1,-3,4}_6,.......,\underbrace{1,-3,4}_{147}, \underbrace{1,-3,4}_{150}$ so the $150$th term is $4$.

And so the sum of the $150$th to $154$th term is

$(4 + 1 + -3) + 4 + 1 =$

$[2] + 4 + 1 = 7$.

......

but if say, we were asked to find the sum of the $213$th term to the $1024$ term we could figure:

There are $(1024 + 1) -213 = 812$ terms.  $812 = 3\times 270 + 2$.  So there are $270$ triplets adding to $270\times 2 = 540$.  There are two more terms. As $1024 = 3\times  341 + 1$ then $a_{1024} = 1$ and $a_{1023} = 4$ so the total is $540 + 1 +4 = 545$.

To verify and $213$ is divisible by $3$ we now then $213$ term is $4$ and our sum is:

$\underbrace{(4 + 1 -3) + (4+1 -3) + ........ + (4+1-3)}_{(213,214,215),(216,217,218)......,(1020,1021,1022)} + 4 + 1=$

$\underbrace{2 + 2+..... + 2}_{3\times 71,..... ,3\times 340} + 5=$

$\underbrace{2 + 2 + .... + 2}_{(340+1)-71\text{ times}}+ 5 =$

$2\times 270 + 5 = 545$.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is which of the three numbers $1,-3,4$ is the $150^{th}$ term. A look at the start shows that the 3rd,6th,9th etc. are all 4. That means, if $k$ is a multiple of $3,$ then the $k^{th}$ term of the sequence is a $4.$ Now you want five (not four as I had before) terms of the sequence starting at the 150-th term. And since $150=3 \cdot 50$ we know the 150-th term is a $4.$ So given the pattern which repeats, the four terms are: $4,1,-3,4,1.$

Comment: If you are to add the 154th term it is $4,1,-3,4,1$.  $150, 151,...,154$ are $5$ terms; not $4$.

Comment: @fleablood I didn't see that. Is it OK if I correct it and cite your comment?

Comment: Of course you can correct!  (I wouldn't have thought that'd ever be an issue!) and you do not need to cite me.  It's a simple oversight is all.